# Разница css и min.css

Tags: css, веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер

Вот уж не знаю, к месту ли данный вопрос, но ранее меня это не интересовало.
Если в файл `style.css` положить уже минифицированные стили, что от этого изменится. (Влияет ли это как-то на браузер или на сервер)
Т.е. если у меня есть стили, например, в **gulp** я минифицировал их и сохранил в файл без добавления суффикса `.min`, на что это влияет.
И соответственно наоборот если в .min положить неминифицированный файл.

На форумах обсуждение данной темы не нашел.
Спасибо)

Comment: Ни на что оно не влияет, разве просто для понимания, что там есть минифицированная версия.

Answer (score 1):

Суффикс `.min` -- общепринятый стандарт выделения минифицированных версий чего-то, что можно минифицировать (`css`/`js`/`html` o_O).

Для конечного лексера разницы нет (разве что разные ненужности для него вырезали и в **очень** больших файлах это выиграет несколько миллисекунд).

Причины выделения таких файлов могут быть разными и зависят только от Вашего желания.

Comment: т.е. по большому счету без разницы есть суффикс .min или нет, главное чтобы минифицированный был?

Comment: Главное или нет - это уже зависит от того, что Вы делаете. Но если в названии будет `min`, а в файле будет человекочитаемый код, то программист ненадолго зависнет %)

Comment: @Other, чего ему виснуть если браузер сам разминифицирует этот css?

Comment: @Grundy, А при чём тут браузер, о Солнцеликий? Я про обычный блокнот, без сорсмапов.

Comment: @Other, а зачем _сорсмапы_ для css?

Comment: @Grundy, Так `.min` не только для CSS.

Comment: в вопросе речь про стили

Comment: @Grundy, А я просветил что и не только.